# Script to save full Google Spreadsheet to folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a function to save a spreadsheet to a folder.
I'm almost there, I think I just need to adjust the synthax of the `createFile` class.

Here is my code:

```
const spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var folder2 = DriveApp.getFoldersById("my_folder_id").next();
var filename2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B97").getValue();

folder2.createFile([I think here is my missing command].setName(filename2));
```

Could someone finish it?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About "create a function to save a spreadsheet" and your script, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. So can you explain about the detail of your goal? For example, you want to copy the active Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike that is correct. In this case I want to copy the whole spreadsheet (not only one sheet) to a new Google Sheets file

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to copy the active Spreadsheet to the specific folder.
- You want to use the filename from `getActiveSheet().getRange("B97").getValue()`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- At `DriveApp.getFoldersById("my_folder_id").next()`, there is no method of `getFoldersById`. When you want to use the folder ID, please use `DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)`.
- Unfortunately, the Spreadsheet cannot be directly created with `createFile()`. In your case, in order to copy the active Spreadsheet, you can use `makeCopy()`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var folderId = "###";  // Please set the folder ID you want to put the copied Spreadsheet.

const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var filename2 = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("B97").getValue();

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy(filename2, folder);
```

#### References:

- [getFolderById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)
- [makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination)